# Why do clustered power calculations fail with two clusters?

Tags: stata, statistical-power

Would someone be able to provide an intuitive explanation for why a power calculation with two clusters (one per arm) fails? For example, when I run this command in Stata (in both clustersampsi and rdpower), it returns a missing value for MDE. I have reviewed the power calculation formula but there is nothing that jumps out as why it would not be able to return a value.

Thanks!

Comment: Because if you have one cluster per arm, it's not a clustered design, is my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give the command.  When I try this, it works

```
. power twomeans 2.6 , k1(1) k2(1)  rho(0.028) sd(0.35) power(.9) m1(30) m2(30)

Performing iteration ...

Estimated experimental-group mean for a two-sample means test
Cluster randomized design, z test assuming sd1 = sd2 = sd
Ho: m2 = m1  versus  Ha: m2 != m1; m2 > m1

Study parameters:

        alpha =    0.0500
        power =    0.9000
           m1 =    2.6000
           sd =    0.3500

Cluster design:

           K1 =         1
           K2 =         1
           M1 =        30
           M2 =        30
           N1 =        30
           N2 =        30
          rho =    0.0280

Estimated effect size and experimental-group mean:

        delta =    0.3943
           m2 =    2.9943
```

In a sense, it **shouldn't** work, though.

The underlying issue is that there's no way to calculate between-cluster variance with only one cluster.   The between-cluster variance is needed for inference because it says how inferences from the one cluster you observed generalise to the clusters you didn't observe. In the power calculation, this issue is worked around by assuming the standard deviation and correlation are known in advance, but you would not typically be willing to do this in the analysis. Since inference isn't possible, power calculations should also not be possible.  (Basically, the power calculation isn't allowing for the loss in degrees of freedom due to estimating rho from the data -- which usually doesn't matter a lot, but does matter when the number of clusters is very small).

Comment: Thanks! I was assuming ICC was calculated using both clusters but I guess it does it within arm?

I was using clustersampsi and rdpower (I have Stata 14 so my power command doesn't work for a clustered design)

Comment: Yes, it has to be within-arm in this case, because the between-arm difference is all used up in being the treatment effect point estimate.  With more than one cluster per arm you could use between-arm contrasts in estimating the ICC.